# Date|Time retornando erro

Tags: php, pdo, php-7

Tenho a **Classe Model** abaixo:

```
namespace classes\mvc\modelos;

use \DateTime;

class ClientesModelos {

    private $idClientes, $data, $nome, $sobreNome, $nascimento;

    public function __construct (
        string $_nome, 
        string $_sobreNome, 
        DateTime $_nacimento
    ) {         
        $this->data        = date('Y-m-d');
        $this->nome        = $_nome;
        $this->sobreNome   = $_sobreNome;
        $this->nascimento  = $_nacimento;
    }       

    public function setIdClientes(int $_idClientes) { $this->idClientes = $_idClientes; }

    public function setData(DateTime $_data): DateTime { $this->data = $_data; }

    public function getIdClientes() : int { return $this->idClientes; }

    public function getData() : DateTime { return $this->data; }

    public function getNome() : string { return $this->nome; }

    public function getSobreNome() : string { return $this->sobreNome; }

    public function getNascimento() : DateTime { return $this->nascimento; }

}
```

E também a **Classe Dao** com o **método inserir**:

```
public function inserir (ClientesModelos $_cliente) : bool {

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO clientes (data, nome, sobreNome, nascimento, documento, telefone, celular, email, senha, bloqueio) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

    $inserir = $this->pdo->prepare ($sql);

    $inserir->bindValue (1, $_cliente->getData());
    $inserir->bindValue (2, $_cliente->getNome());
    $inserir->bindValue (3, $_cliente->getSobreNome());
    $inserir->bindValue (4, $_cliente->getNascimento()->format("Y-m-d"));

    return $inserir->execute();

}
```

**Resumi** ao **máximo** para ficar apenas o **necessário** para a **resposta** da **dúvida**.

O **problema**:

Quando *rodo* a **index.php**

```
$cliente = new ClientesModelos (
         'Carlos',
         'Alberto',
         new DateTime('1970-12-20')
);

$clienteControle = new ClientesControles();

$clienteControle->inserir ($cliente);
```

Método da **Classe controle**:

```
public function inserir(ClientesModelos $_pessoa) : string {

    if ( !is_object($_pessoa) ) return 'Uma pessoa precisa ser passada como parâmtro' ;
    else return $this->ClientesDao->inserir($_pessoa)  ? 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso' : 'Erro no processo do cadastro';

}
```

**Método** **inserir** da **classe** **Dao**:

```
public function inserir (ClientesModelos $_cliente) : bool {

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO clientes (data, nome, sobreNome, nascimento, documento, telefone, celular, email, senha, bloqueio) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

    $inserir = $this->pdo->prepare ($sql);

    $inserir->bindValue (1, $_cliente->getData());
    $inserir->bindValue (2, $_cliente->getNome());
    $inserir->bindValue (3, $_cliente->getSobreNome());
    $inserir->bindValue (4, $_cliente->getNascimento()->format("Y-m-d"));

    return $inserir->execute();

}
```

Obtenho o **seguinte** **erro**:

> **Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos::getData() must be an instance of DateTime, string returned in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos.php:40 Stack trace: #0 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesDao.php(20): classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos->getData() #1 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\controles\ClientesControles.php(22): classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesDao->inserir(Object(classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos)) #2 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\visoes\ClientesVisoes.php(31): classes\mvc\controles\ClientesControles->inserir(Object(classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos)) #3 D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\index.php(18): classes\mvc\visoes\ClientesVisoes->html() #4 {main} thrown in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos.php on line 40**

No entanto o **objeto** **retorna** o **DateTime** corretamente.

Comment: A função `date`, apesar do nome, retorna uma string. Então `$this->data` é uma string, mas o método `getData` indica que o retorno é um `DateTime`. Então ou vc muda o tipo da variável (atribua o valor `new DateTime()` a ela, por exemplo), ou o tipo que o método retorna, de forma que ambos sejam o mesmo...

Comment: ok, obrigado! A solução da resposta abaixo clareou a minha mente!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro está no tipo do arquivo para inserir no banco.

Para inserir a data no banco, você tem que enviar como string, normalmente no formato `Y-m-d` e o retorno do método `getData()` retorna o objeto `DateTime`.

Você pode mudar o método `getData()`

```
public function getData() : string { return $this->data->format('Y-m-d'); }
```

ou depois no DAO

```
$inserir->bindValue (1, $_cliente->getData()->format('Y-m-d'));
```

igual está no nascimento

```
$inserir->bindValue (4, $_cliente->getNascimento()->format("Y-m-d"));
```

Comment: Entendi. Só que no banco o tipo é Date

Comment: deu certo. Obrigado!